# Remove "Powered by Cognito forms"

Tags: cognito-forms

How can I remove "powered by Cognito forms" from my form, when I copy your code to my website?

Do I need to pay for a higher package?

Answer (score 2):

With the recent release of our [referral program](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/160/account--organizations/plans--billing/referral-program), we completely removed all branding everywhere for customers on our paid plans (forms, emails, etc.) and included simple branding like "Powered by Cognito Forms" for customers on our free Individual plan. The branding also doubles as referral links, which help customers earn credit that they can apply to a paid plan in the future.

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com)